# Selenium - Extracting the text from http get request

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jsoup

I am loading the url using driver.get method inside my selenium test

```
driver.get("myurl");
      String text = driver.getPageSource();
```

myurl has plain text (which will be expected data for my tests)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link title="Wrap Long Lines" href="resource://gre-resources/plaintext.css" type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet" /></head><body><pre>**I need this text**</pre></body></html>
```

Is there any inbuilt method in Selenium to do this OR Do I need to go for Jsoup etc.

Comment: Please add a few more details to the question. I did not understand the sentence "myurl has plain text (which will be expected data for my tests)". Are you trying to pass parameters to the url? As far as getting the data from the html is concerned, that can be easily done by using xpath / css selector query.

Comment: When we do get request to http://myurl it gives Plain text in browser

Comment: If possible, please mention which site / url you are navigating to?

Comment: Its hosted internally so you will not be having access to it. The output in browser for myurl is >>    <Base Unit *>

Comment: What is driver.getPageSource() returning?

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link title="Wrap Long Lines" href="resource://gre-resources/plaintext.css" type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet" /></head><body><pre>**I need this text**</pre></body></html>

Comment: And you wish to retrieve the ** I need this text **? This can be done by WebElement textNeeded = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//pre")); textNeeded.getText();

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Manali. Your solution worked. Adding the code snippet here >

```
driver.get("myurl");
    String text = driver.getPageSource();
    String mytext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//pre")).getText();
    System.out.println(mytext);
```